# Making a custom dot access dict compatible with np.array()

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I have a custom dict class, allowing dot access:

```py
class dotDict(dict):
    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

I need this to be compatible with `numpy.array()`. Just like this, I get the error `KeyError: '__array_struct__'`. If I try to define a custom method `__array_struct__` with the help of an AI tool I always get `ValueError: invalid __array_struct__`.

I have tried a lot of variants along the lines of

```py
    def __array_struct__(self):
        return self.data.__array_interface__["data"], self.data.dtype
```

but I always get `ValueError: invalid __array_struct__`. I have also tried defining other methods such as `__array__` with no success. I find it quite hard to find documentation on how to do this correctly.

Any ideas?

The background: I need the class to be compatible with `np.atleast_1d`, which internally calls `asanyarray`, which is quite obscure, but it seems to call `np.array()`.

Comment: why a dict in the first place?

Comment: You should generally avoid subclassing `dict` itself. If you really need to create a dict subclass, prefer `collections.UserDict`

Comment: `atleasat_1d` is just a variante on the basic `np.array`, making sure that the result is 1d.  `np.array` is, internally, a quite complex function, though in the comon usage `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])` is seems clear enough.  It has to determine if there are iterables (like lists), and the type of the elements.  It's hard to tell how you want a `dict` to be array like.

Comment: @Anentropic I want it to be compatible with existing code that was written with dicts. So `dict.item` should work just as well as `dict['item']`

Comment: @Brian61354270 As far as I understand `UserDict` is deprecated, see the official documentation

Comment: @hpaulj I want the array representation of the custom dict to be just the same as for the normal dict, so no change in functionality

Comment: It seems that the presence of `__getattr__` causes the problem. If I remove this but leave `__setattr__` etc., the problem disappears. But then of course the class doesn't function as intended anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution! My class is now:

```py
class dotDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item == "__array_struct__" or item == "__array_interface__":
            raise AttributeError
        else:
            return self.get(item)

    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__

    def __array__(self):
        return np.array(self.__dict__())

    def __dict__(self):
        out_dict = dict()
        for key, value in self.items():
            out_dict[key] = value
        return out_dict
```

When attempting to convert an unkown object to an array, numpy first looks for `__array_interface__` and `__array_struct__`. If those don't exist (which we tell numpy explicitly here through the `AttributeError`, then it falls back to `__array__`. Since the array representation here is very simple (just an array containing the data from our custom dict as a normal dict), this is good enough.