# Making __array_interface__ return the correct thing for a custom dict

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a custom dict:

```py
class CustomDict(dict):
    @property
    def __array_interface__(self):
        return {
            'version': 3,
            'typestr': '<f8',
            'data': (id(self), False),
            'shape': (len(self),),
        }
```

When calling

```py
custom_data = CustomDict({'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0})
numpy_array = numpy.array(custom_data)
```

I get `[1.4821969e-323 1.2284441e-311 1.4821969e-323]`.

The result should instead be `array({'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0}, dtype=object)`, just like when calling `numpy.array({'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0, 'c': 3.0})`.

How do I need to change `__array_interface__`? I have looked through the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.interface.html#python-side), but don't really understand it well enough.

Comment: Why are you specifying `<f8` if you want an object instead of floats, and `shape: (len(self),)` if the shape should be `()`?

Comment: I've only used `__array_interface__` to learn about an array, things like the shape, strides, and `data`.  It returns a `dict`.  Where did you see anything about using it to determine how an array, custom or not, operates?

Comment: @Barmar so `typestr` should be `'O'` and `'shape': ()`? Then I get a `Windows fatal exception: access violation`.

Comment: @hpaullj I need my custom dict to be compatible with `numpy.array()`, so it should return the same as when using it with a normal dict. Apparently you need to set an `__array_interface__` to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. My class is now:

```py
class CustomDict(dict):
    def __dict__(self):
        # return custom dict as type normal dict
        out_dict = dict()
        for key, value in self.items():
            out_dict[key] = value
        return out_dict

    def __array__(self):
        return np.array(self.__dict__())
```

Numpy first checks if the attributes `__array_interface__` and `__array_struct__` exist, and if they don't it falls back to `__array__`. The former two could be used to specify an array representation in complex cases, but in this case it's very simple, I just want to return an array with as the sole item the standard dict representation of `CustomDict`, hence `np.array(self.__dict__())`.

For a slightly more complex case see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77046584/7705804, an answer to another similar question of mine.